# Windows serivce not calling the updated function within a DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll, windows-services

I have a windows service written in vb.net. This service calls a function which is written in an another project and this project is also referred in my service project(i.e the DLL is referred in my service project). Recently I updated this function and when i re-installed my service and checked, the service is working with the previous version of the function and not with the updated one. I have cleaned the entire solution and then re-built it also. Still its calling the older version of the function. Please help.

Comment: If you are totally sure it is still calling the old function then you must have a copy of the old library hanging around either in the working directory of the service, in the GAC, or in a Windows search path.

Comment: I have un-installed the previous service and then tried by installing the service again in a new directory. But still I am facing the same issue. Its not calling the updated function. Do I need to remove the reference to that DLL and add it again and try?

Comment: Do the results of the service get cached in the client's internet cache?  Are you sure the DLL in the newly installed location is definitely the new version (have you incremented the version in the project and then verified that the one in the installed directory on the server has that new version number on the binary)?

Comment: I have removed the reference to that dll and then added it again. Now it works.

Comment: In that case, you probably had it as a file reference rather than a project reference.